# How do I add an alpha channel to an existing Android color in xml

Tags: android, android-resources, android-color

I have the following color in `values/colors.xml`:

```
<color name="grey_1">#0F0E10</color>
```

I want to reference this color in a gradient:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="-90"
        android:startColor="#000F0E10"
        android:endColor="#990F0E10"/>
</shape>
```

However, this duplicates the RGB color definition. Ideally, I'd like to write something like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="-90"
        android:startColor="alpha(00, @color/grey_1)"
        android:endColor="alpha(99, @color/grey_1)"/>
</shape>
```

or this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="-90"
        android:startColor="@color/grey_1"
        android:startTransparency="#00"
        android:endColor="@color/grey_1"
        android:endTransparency="#99"/>
</shape>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, It's not possible. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it in code. You can get a color like this,

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.<the color>);
```

You can turn it into ARGB like this:

```
int a = Color.alpha(color);
int r = Color.red(color);
int g = Color.green(color);
int b = Color.blue(color);
```

Now you can re-create the color with whatever alpha you want:

```
color = Color.argb(<new alpha>, r, g, b);
```

This means of course you'd need to construct your drawable from code. Not as clean but possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in API 23 and higher with a [`ColorStateList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList).

From the docs:

> Starting with API 23, items may optionally define an android:alpha
>   attribute to modify the base color's opacity. This attribute takes a
>   either floating-point value between 0 and 1 or a theme attribute that
>   resolves as such. The item's overall color is calculated by
>   multiplying by the base color's alpha channel by the alpha value. For
>   example, the following item represents the theme's accent color at 50%
>   opacity:

```
<item android:state_enabled="false"
      android:color="?android:attr/colorAccent"
      android:alpha="0.5" />
```

Thus, in my case, I would do:

**`color/gradient_start_color.xml`**:

```
<item android:color="@color/grey_1"
      android:alpha="0" />
```

**`color/gradient_end_color.xml`**:

```
<item android:color="@color/grey_1"
      android:alpha="0.6" />
```

**`drawable/gradient.xml`**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="-90"
        android:startColor="@color/gradient_start_color"
        android:endColor="@color/gradient_end_color" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to point out that it can be done programmatically with [ColorStateList.withAlpha()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList#withAlpha(int))

like so:

```
csl.withAlpha(0) //transparent
csl.withAlpha(255) //opaque
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set two distinct colors as the starting and the ending colors.

Remember that colors are defined this way : #AARRGGBB for Alpha, Red, Green and Blue.

Once the app is launched, ressources are in read only mode. You can't change them programmatically on a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ColorUtils` class from `androidx.core.graphics` package, for example;

```
 int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.border_active_default);
 circle.setFillColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color,50));
```

Then you don't have to implement your own custom approach.